# Multicast using Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to send messages to an agent list. To do so, I wrote this function:

```
fun  multicast :: "[msg, agent, agent list]=> event set" 
  where  
  multicast_Nil:      " multicast M A [] ={}"   
| multicast_Cons: " multicast M A (x#xs) =  {Says x A M} Un multicast M A xs"

fun knows :: "[agent, event list] => msg set" where 
  knows_Nil:  "knows A [] = initState A"
| knows_Cons: "knows A (ev # evs) = 
    (case ev of Says A' B X => 
       if A'=A then insert X (knows A evs) else knows A evs)
```

The problem is that I wasn't able to define the corresponding code in the knows function in order to add the sent message to the knowledge of all the agents in the agent list.

Comment: First of all, your function can be rewritten as `multicast M A xs = (⋃x∈set xs. Says x A M)`. Second, unless you have a good reason to use a list of agents here, I would simply use a set and then write e.g. `multicast M A Bs = (⋃B∈Bs. Says B A M)`. Third, you will have to go into more detail about what your `knows` function is. There is a lot of context missing from your question.

Comment: Sorry for this ambiguity. The knows function adds the sent message to the receiver's event list (for the says event) . It deals also with other events (gets and notes). My goal is to modify this function in order to have an another event multicasting messages.                                    fun knows :: "[agent,  event list] => msg set"
where  knows_Nil: "knows A  [] = initState A"
| knows_Cons:
    "knows A  (ev # evs) = (case ev of
           Says A' B X => if A'=A then insert X (knows A  evs) else knows A  evs

Comment: Again, it's probably better to use a set here instead of a list. Then you can simply write `definition knows :: "agent ⇒ event set ⇒ msg set" where "knows A evs = {X |X B. Says A B X ∈ evs}"`

Comment: I think what you really want here is to maintain some kind of global state that contains the knowledge of every agent, i.e. a state of the form `agent ⇒ event set`. Initially, that state would simply be your `initState`, and your functions can then modify that state. Of course, your global state can also just be a list or set of all messages that have ever been sent, then you just append new events to that list.

Comment: but in such case only A receives the message?